# 'The resource cannot be found' using HttpPost in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I see that my problem is a common error and have tried many answers to this problem but it's still not working for me.  So, to start form the beginning, I have a partial form in an MVC project which uses the Html.BeginForm helper:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new{@class = "form-class"}))
```

"MyAction" and "MyController" are not the actual names but they are resolved as the underlined names confirm.  My action in my controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(int id, FormCollection form)
    {
     EditedData dt = new EditedData();
      // does some db submits and returns edited data

        return View(dt);
    }
```

So, the common problem it seems, is that using [HttpPost] returns the error "The resource cannot be found'.  I've debugged with [HttpPost] commented out which hits MyAction so it's not routing (?).  My global.asax hasn't been altered:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

As I say, I've tried other answers in other posts which seems to work for the poster but I'm still havng a problem.  What am I missing?

P.S. In View Source I see the form tag reads:

```
<form method="post" action="690" id="form1">
```

when action should point to MyAction. How do I set Html.BeginForm to point to 'MyAction'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the action's `id` parameter being an int (value type), it cannot be passed as a null reference. So, you need to explicitly set it to 0 in the `BeginForm` call (in the view) or make it nullable.

Basically, the routing engine cannot resolve your action and controller based on the data you've given it (action name and controller name) + the route mappings.

Sample (in case you decide to keep the parameter as `int`):

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new { id = 0 }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-class" }))
```

This overload will then match the signature that you specify in the controller. When you're editing, just replace the `0` with whatever model property matches; for example:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", new { id=Model.ID }, FormMethod.Post, new{ @class = "form-class"})) %>
```

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.  But I want the action to read action="MyAction" and not action="690". I don't see how setting it to 0 or null would solve my problem.  Can you post an example?

Comment: @marceln I was about to add an answer that basically said the same as your last edit, so I added the little bit that wasn't the same to yours. Roll back the edit if you don't approve.

Comment: @user2284341: You have two samples above. Take your pick :). It will work.